# Define Excel custom number format color via HEX or RGB

Tags: excel, colors, formatting, rgb, number-formatting

Is it possible to define a custom number format via HEX or RGB, as in the following?

```
[Black][>5]0.0;[Red][<0]-0.0;[Color34]0.0
```

I'm looking for a dark orange color (#FF9900), and `[Orange]` doesn't work.

I've tried the full spectrum of 56 colors, as suggested by [this article](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm#chart), or the [few built in by name](http://searchengineland.com/easy-to-advanced-uses-of-cell-formatting-in-excel-130203) but none are even close to the correct shade of orange.

The few Excel has built in don't include orange:

```
[BLACK][GREEN][RED][BLUE][CYAN][MAGENTA][WHITE][YELLOW]
```

Comment: What Excel version are you using? For me (Excel 2016) `[Black][>5]0.0;[Red][<0]-0.0;[Color45]0.0` is working and `[Color45]` produces exactly the orange `#FF9900` as listed in your linked color palette for values from 0 to 5.

Comment: Interesting - I'm using Excel for Mac 14.7.1 (161129), and move the worksheet file between home (mac) and work (Win 7).  I've made every effort to stay away from techniques and functionality (collections being notable example for my project) that isn't universal.  Thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts?: Ask Microsoft why they are using different color indices between Windows Excel and Mac Excel? Maybe it's about the different general color system RGB vs. CYMK? Btw.: I'm using apples only as fruits ;-). But the color indices differ between Excel and Openoffice/Libreoffice Calc also. There the best orange similar color is [COLOR36] in 64-bit Ubuntu and [COLOR29] in 32-bit Windows.

Comment: The difference between Libreoffice in 64-bit Ubuntu and Libreoffice in 32-bit Windows leads to the assumption, that the indices are depending on the platform (64-bit or 32-bit) also. For me, Libreoffice in 64-bit Ubuntu has 64 color indices (1-64) available while Libreoffice in 32-bit Windows has only 32 color indices (1-32) available.

Comment: @AxelRichter - interesting insight.  I take it then the only syntax to define a color is `[ColorXX]` and not via HEX or RGB?  I'm limited to the 64 (or 32) predefined colors?

Comment: Yes the only ways I know to achieve different font colors depending on values are: 1. Specifying colors in number formats - for this Microsoft itself documents only the 8 named ones [Black]...[Red], even [ColorNN] is an undocumented hack. 2. Conditional formatting. 3. Using VBA.

Comment: @AxelRichter - make that last comment an answer and I'll accept it as solved.  Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making comments to an answer:

The only ways I know to achieve different font colors depending on values are:

1. Specifying colors in number formats - for this Microsoft itself documents only the 8 named ones [Black]...[Red], even [ColorNN] is an undocumented hack.
2. Conditional formatting.
3. Using VBA.

To specifying colors in number formats one needs to know the [guidelines for customizing a number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4#bm1). There only the 8 named colors [Black], [Green], [White], [Blue], [Magenta], [Yellow], [Cyan], [Red] are documented. But using [ColorNN] with `NN` being the color index is also possible for 56 indexed colors. To determine which colors are indexed with which index, one could using the following `VBA` macro:

```
Sub UDColorNumberFormats()
 With ActiveSheet

  For i = 1 To 56
   sNumberFormat = "[Color" & i & "]0"
   .Cells(i, 1).Value = sNumberFormat
   .Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = sNumberFormat
   .Cells(i, 2).Value = 888888
   .Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = i
  Next

 End With
End Sub
```

Running this macro in Excel for Windows (versions 2007 up to 2016 tested) will show, that the [Color45] for example is orange color. But if we take a look at the Microsoft documentation of [ColorIndex Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443(v=office.15).aspx), we must see, that even Microsoft shows different indexed colors. Maybe simply not updated since earlier versions?

As @Zephyr Mays had to realize, Excel for Mac also uses different indexed colors. So Excel for Mac and Excel for Windows are not 100% compatible in this point. But the macro should run in Excel for Mac also. So one could check whether the indexed colors, which Excel for Mac uses, are the ones which are shown in documentation for ColorIndex Property. If so, then Excel for Mac uses a default color palette from earlier versions than Excel for Windows uses. This could be called a bug in my opinion and could be reported to Microsoft as such.

As I noted in comments above, the color indices used in [COLORNN] are different in Libreoffice/Openoffice Calc also. There they are even different from the interior color indices. And they are dependent on the platform (64-bit or 32-bit) also. For me, Libreoffice in 64-bit Ubuntu has 64 color indices (1-64) available while Libreoffice in 32-bit Windows has only 32 color indices (1-32) available. But this behavior is not a bug since Libreoffice/Openoffice Calc is not 100% Excel compatible and does not want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

What about using:

```
Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(&HFF, &H99, &H0)
```

Comment: That is actually the way I'm currently doing so, but sInce I've already defined around 6,000 conditional formats for this sheet I'm trying to reduce the number for performance reasons.  I'd like to set the text color in the number format, but there doesn't seem to be any reasonable approximation of orange.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through many threads like this, but the simplest solution for coloring numbers in CELLS is to use conditional formatting.

But for CHARTS, the easiest way is to use the basic font formatting option -- you can specify any hex value there. If you want to colorize only negative numbers, say, you can override the font formatting for positives by editing it in the number format code.

For instance: I want to color negative numbers on my chart scale Dark Red (a color that isn't one of the 56 colors Excel precoded).

1. select the chart's y-axis, go to font options in the toolbar, and turned the whole axis Dark Red.
2. To turn positive numbers black again, go to format axis -> axis options -> number -> format code.
3. Then specify positive numbers to be black "[Color1]#,##0%;-#,##0%".
4. Voila - only the negative numbers retain the Dark Red, while positives are hard coded to be black.

You still have to have one of your colors be one of the 56 Excel presets, but this allows you to set one to a different color.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like excel uses ABGR (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) instead of RGBA (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha).

Dark orange color, #FF9900 in RGB should be written with #0099FF in excel (#FF0099FF with alpha).

```
Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = &hFF0099FF
```